# Uploading an image from an html form input to database blob column

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli, blob

I want to upload data from a html form to a database, here's my html code:

```
<form method="post" action="events.php" id="formhh" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="Titre" required>
    <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg" name="Image" required>
    <textarea name="Description" form="formhh" required></textarea>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="style" value="1" required>
        <input type="radio" name="style" value="2" required>
        <input type="radio" name="style" value="3" required>
        <input type="radio" name="style" value="4" required>
        <input type="radio" name="style" value="5" required>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary me-5">
</form>
```

and the "events.php" that connects and sends data to the database (named "isticg"):

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "isticg");

$Titre = $_POST['Titre'];
$Img = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn ,file_get_contents($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name']));
$Desc = $_POST['Description'];
$Style = $_POST['style'];



$stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into evenements(Titre, Image, Description,style) values(?,?,?,?)");

$stmt->bind_param("sbsi",$Titre,$Img,$Desc,$Style);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

?>
```

everything works fine except of the image, here's [how it looks in phpmyadmin after i do a test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiDEX.png)

I am a beginner and just started learning php for this project, so please if you could provide an explanation with your answers.

Comment: Being a beginner, the *last ever thing* you should be doing is storing blobs in the database.

Comment: Didn't find another way to store images there so.. If you have a suggestion please tell me

Comment: Seriously? Not a single suggestion to just copy the file to where it belongs - to some directory in the filesystem?

Comment: Do yourself a favor, instead of doing something unnatural, learn some basic things. Such as debugging. Before blaming a database for not storing your file, take time to verify, whether you sent anything to that database. And after that proceed to storing the image where it belongs - in the filesystem.

Comment: Always do one thing at a time. There is no such thing as "Uploading an image from an html form input to database blob column". You can only upload an HTML form contents to the web server. So you have to do so. And verify that every single form element has been uploaded correctly. Only after that proceed to storing this data. One thing at a time.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fixed it!
I changed the php code to this:

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=isticg", "root", "");

$Titre = $_POST['Titre'];
$Img = file_get_contents($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name']);
$Desc = $_POST['Description'];
$Style = $_POST['style'];



$stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into evenements values('',?,?,?,?)");

$stmt->bindParam(1,$Titre);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$Img);
$stmt->bindParam(3,$Desc);
$stmt->bindParam(4,$Style);

$stmt->execute();

?>
```

Comment: Could explain the code